# When I move checkbox position to navbar, then hide and show sidebar is not working

Tags: html, css

In this demo I used `checkbox` to hide and show the sidebar respectively to move content to the left side but my question is when I change `checkbox` from current position to navbar it doesn't work. Please help me. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/txud649b/)

### index.html

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <h2>My Header</h2>
    </div>

    <div id="navbar">
        <h2>My Navbar</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <input id="slide-sidebar" type="checkbox" role="button" />
        <label for="slide-sidebar"><span>close</span></label>

        <div class="sidebar-left">
            <h2>Lecture Dates</h2>
            <p>11/07 - Lecture on Caesar</p>
            <p>11/08 - Lecture on Caesar</p>
            <p>11/09 - Lecture on Caesar</p>
            <p>11/10 - Lecture on Caesar</p>
            <p>11/11 - Lecture on Caesar</p>
            <p>11/07 - Lecture on Caesar</p>
            <p>11/08 - Lecture on Caesar</p>
            <p>11/09 - Lecture on Caesar</p>
            <p>11/10 - Lecture on Caesar</p>
            <p>11/11 - Lecture on Caesar</p>
            <p>11/07 - Lecture on Caesar</p>
        </div>


        <div class="portfolio">

            <h1>Hello World</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque viverra mauris nec sem condimentum pellentesque. Praesent tincidunt non nulla in ullamcorper. Nulla lacinia, magna ac iaculis sodales, elit odio sagittis nisl, vel egestas sem quam sit amet leo. Maecenas pellentesque porta cursus. In ornare, diam eget maximus fermentum, felis lacus bibendum nunc, aliquam egestas dui ligula ut ante.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque viverra mauris nec sem condimentum pellentesque. Praesent tincidunt non nulla in ullamcorper. Nulla lacinia, magna ac iaculis sodales, elit odio sagittis nisl, vel egestas sem quam sit amet leo. Maecenas pellentesque porta cursus. In ornare, diam eget maximus fermentum, felis lacus bibendum nunc, aliquam egestas dui ligula ut ante.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque viverra mauris nec sem condimentum pellentesque. Praesent tincidunt non nulla in ullamcorper. Nulla lacinia, magna ac iaculis sodales, elit odio sagittis nisl, vel egestas sem quam sit amet leo. Maecenas pellentesque porta cursus. In ornare, diam eget maximus fermentum, felis lacus bibendum nunc, aliquam egestas dui ligula ut ante.</p>
            <h2>Hello World</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque viverra mauris nec sem condimentum pellentesque. Praesent tincidunt non nulla in ullamcorper. Nulla lacinia, magna ac iaculis sodales, elit odio sagittis nisl, vel egestas sem quam sit amet leo. Maecenas pellentesque porta cursus. In ornare, diam eget maximus fermentum, felis lacus bibendum nunc, aliquam egestas dui ligula ut ante.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque viverra mauris nec sem condimentum pellentesque. Praesent tincidunt non nulla in ullamcorper. Nulla lacinia, magna ac iaculis sodales, elit odio sagittis nisl, vel egestas sem quam sit amet leo. Maecenas pellentesque porta cursus. In ornare, diam eget maximus fermentum, felis lacus bibendum nunc, aliquam egestas dui ligula ut ante.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque viverra mauris nec sem condimentum pellentesque. Praesent tincidunt non nulla in ullamcorper. Nulla lacinia, magna ac iaculis sodales, elit odio sagittis nisl, vel egestas sem quam sit amet leo. Maecenas pellentesque porta cursus. In ornare, diam eget maximus fermentum, felis lacus bibendum nunc, aliquam egestas dui ligula ut ante.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque viverra mauris nec sem condimentum pellentesque. Praesent tincidunt non nulla in ullamcorper. Nulla lacinia, magna ac iaculis sodales, elit odio sagittis nisl, vel egestas sem quam sit amet leo. Maecenas pellentesque porta cursus. In ornare, diam eget maximus fermentum, felis lacus bibendum nunc, aliquam egestas dui ligula ut ante.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <h3>My Footer</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

### styles.css

```
[body {
    background-color: #9c9f84;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-size: 14px;
}
#header {
    background-color: #5c755e;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
}
#header h2 {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}
#footer {
    background-color: #5c755e;
    margin: 10px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    font-size: 110%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
}
#footer h3 {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}
#navbar {
    background-color: #5c755e;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 90px;
}
#navbar h2 {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}
#slide-sidebar + label:after {
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
#wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
.portfolio {
    background-color: #e5e4d7;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 110%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-transition: left 1s ease;
    transition: left 1s ease;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: auto;
}
.sidebar-left {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #e5e4d7;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 105%;
    width: 260px;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    -moz-transition: margin-left 1s ease;
    transition: margin-left 1s ease;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -moz-transition: width 0.5s ease, padding 0.5s ease;
    transition: width 0.5s ease, padding 0.5s ease;
}
input:checked ~ .sidebar-left {
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    -moz-transition: width 0.5s ease, padding 0.5s ease;
    transition: width 0.5s ease, padding 0.5s ease;
}][1]
```

Comment: It isn't working because you have written `input:checked ~ .portfolio`. CSS can not select in upward direction, you will need jQuery or JS to do this.

Comment: yes, but give me some idea for this (using jquery) or give some useful link so i can read and implement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sumit wrote:

> It isn't working because you have written input:checked ~ .portfolio. CSS can not select in upward direction, you will need jQuery or JS to do this.

You can use following jQuery code:

```
$("#slide-sidebar").change(function() {
  $(".sidebar-left").toggleClass("show");
});
```

And this CSS code:

```
.sidebar-left.show {
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  -moz-transition: width 0.5s ease, padding 0.5s ease;
  transition: width 0.5s ease, padding 0.5s ease;
}
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/txud649b/1/).

Comment: @tusharbalar I'm glad it helps, but please avoid writing not constructive comments which won't be helpful for other visitors. Consider deleting your comment.